# Apply a function that requires seq() in R

Tags: r, sum, apply, seq

I am trying to run a summation on each row of dataframe. Let's say I want to take the sum of *100n^2*, from *n=1* to *n=4*.

```
> df <- data.frame(n = seq(1:4),a = rep(100))
> df
  n   a
1 1 100
2 2 100
3 3 100
4 4 100
```

**Simpler example:**

Let's make `fun1` our example summation function. I can pull 100 out because I can just multiply it in later.

```
fun <- function(x) {
    i <- seq(1,x,1)
    sum(i^2) }
```

I want to then apply this function to each row to the dataframe, where `df$n` provides the upper bound of the summation.

The desired outcome would be as follows, in `df$b`:

```
> df
  n   a  b
1 1 100  1
2 2 100  5
3 3 100 14
4 4 100 30
```

To achieve these results I've tried the apply function

```
apply(df$n,1,phi)
```

and also with df converted into a matrix

```
mat <- as.matrix(df)
apply(mat[1,],1,phi)
```

Both return an error:

```
Error in seq.default(1, x, 1) : 'to' must be of length 1
```

I understand this error, in that I understand why `seq` requires a 'to' value of length 1. I don't know how to go forward.

I have also tried the same while reading the dataframe as a matrix.

**Maybe less simple example:**

In my case I only need to multiply the results above, `df$b`, by 100 (or `df$a`) to get my final answer for each row. In other cases, though, the second value might be more entrenched, for example *a^i*. How would I call on both variables, *a* and *n*?

**Underlying question:**

My underlying goal is to apply a summation to each row of a dataframe (or a matrix). The above questions stem from my attempt to do so using seq(), as I saw advised in an answer on this site. I will gladly accept an answer that obviates the above questions with a different way to run a summation.

Comment: often you can vectorise, in this case `cumsum(df$n^2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are applying `seq` it doesn't take a vector for `from` and `to`.  So we can loop and do it

```
df$b <- sapply(df$n, fun)
df$b
#[1]  1  5 14 30
```

Or we can `Vectorize`

```
Vectorize(fun)(df$n)
#[1]  1  5 14 30
```

Comment: Wow I have no idea what I was doing. I could have sworn I tried this first